# Parent level does not display users with 'limited access'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

SharePoint 2013 - I've granted a user permission to a specific folder within a library.  When I look at the permissions of that library, I do not see that user having 'limited access'.  They are able to access that folder navigating through the library but owners cannot see who might have 'limited access' within that library.  How do I get the 'limited access' users to display in the permissions list?

Comment: are you inheriting the permission on that library? also user part of any sharepoint group?